# Why is this hover effect pushing the other elements that are next to it away?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have divs that contain each individual arrow (one for the greater than text and another for the less than text). However, when I hover over the less than arrow, it pushes all the other elements to the right a bit. How can I have the hover effect not push any other elements away?

This is my HTML:

```
<div className="datepicker-wrapper">
        <div className="dates">
          <div className="arrows prev-month">&lt;</div>
          <div className="months">
            <div className="start-month">February</div>
            <div className="end-month">March</div>
          </div>

          <div className="days"></div>
          <div className="arrows next-month">&gt;</div>
        </div>

        <div className="selected-dates">
          <div className="check-in-date">02/13/2020</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
@import 'variables.css';

.datepicker-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .dates {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .selected-dates {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: default;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .dates .arrows .previous-month {
}

.datepicker-wrapper .dates .arrows:hover {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: var(--light-gray);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .dates .months {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

**NOTE**
I've tried giving the `arrows prev-month` div a set width, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: If the width is changing it would be normal for surrounding element to move.

Comment: Ah ok, so do I need to give a width to start out with as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give the `width` and `height` only on hover.. try to give the styles to the arrows anyway, and on hover only change the `background-color`

```css
.datepicker-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .dates {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .selected-dates {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  cursor: default;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .dates .arrows {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.datepicker-wrapper .dates .arrows:hover {
  background: #c1c1c1;
}

.datepicker-wrapper .dates .months {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="datepicker-wrapper">
        <div class="dates">
          <div class="arrows prev-month">&lt;</div>
          <div class="months">
            <div class="start-month">February</div>
            <div class="end-month">March</div>
          </div>

          <div class="days"></div>
          <div class="arrows next-month">&gt;</div>
        </div>

        <div class="selected-dates">
          <div class="check-in-date">02/13/2020</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works, I was just about to try that :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the styles on `:hover` impacts [the CSS box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#What_is_the_CSS_box_model) for the `.arrows` element:

[image]

All four of those impact the overall space an element takes.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So if I wanted a hover effect, but without pushing away the elements next to it, how would I accomplish that? Or what's the best way to accomplish that?